# is it illegal for a minor to contact a minor if the second minor's parents have instructed them not to do so?

Tags: is-x-legal, minor

I am 16 yrs old and my boyfriend's parents have told my boyfriend not to contact me (and have told me not to contact him) because they disapprove, and believe I am not a real person since they have never actually met me.

My boyfriend however has met me before he moved.  We mainly talk online now, and they say I may be predator or something malicious, which is not true.

They told him not to contact me, but I reached out to him and his best friend online to let him know that I would be willing to have a phone call with them so they could talk to me and get to know me and realize I'm a real person.

Thus: is it illegal for me to contact him if  his parents told him not to, even though I initiated the contact and he was really just talking to me because he cares to try to fix it between us?

Comment: Details will depend on where you are (which country, possibly which state) and where your friend is. Generally, the *legal guardians* of a minor can restrict contacts they deem harmful, and they might be able to get a restraining order from a court.

Answer (score 8):

If, so far, you only had contact trough phone or internet, it is somewhat understandable that parents are afraid that their son/daughter falls for some internet-rip-off or some pervert with a fake profile.

It may upset your or his parents, but continued contact is not in itself illegal (illegal as in "you could be sent to jail for it"), just because they say so. The parents could in theory get a restraining order or inform the youth safety agency (or however that is called in your place), but to do that, they would need to provide some rationale as to why they think that you (or your boyfriend) are an impostor.

I think, this should really be solved on the social level, and your best option would really be to physically meet your boyfriend, maybe even when your or his parents are around.

After all, Romeo and Julia didn't stop meeting just because they weren't allowed to...

Comment: And look how that ended.

Comment: "they would need to provide some rationale as to _why they think_ that you (or your boyfriend) are an impostor" - no, they would have to provide some rationale that you _are_ an impostor. Or not an impostor, but a 16 year old trying to harm their child.

Comment: @gnasher729 From the question, it looks like the OPs parents think the boyfriend is an impostor _and_ the other's parents think the same of the OP. With "impostor" here I means someone who is in fact much older than what they say.